# ajax json en django

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates

Estoy trabajando Django, vengo con el pensamiento de ajax en php, que lo he hecho algunas veces.

tengo un ajax en mi template asi:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'apis/',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    data:{
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
    },   
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response)
        $('#mensaje').val(response['foo'])
    },
    error: function(response){
        console.log(response)
    }
});

</script>
```

quiero devolver varios registros de mi bd, para luego recorrerlos, se me ocurre a mi en json, aunque podria ser otro formato.

si ejecuto esta prueba me devuelve bien, los datos y se los puedo pasar a un input. finalmente es una prueba y todo ok.

```
def api(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return JsonResponse({'foo':'bar'})
```

el problema esta, cuando en vez de ese diccionario manual que devuelvo hago una consulta a mi bd.
e intento devolver el resultado de esa consulta:

```
productos = Producto.objects.all()
```

todos los productos de la bd, si lo hago en otra funcion, como para mostrar mis productos, todo ok.
apenas tengo 3 productos, como parte de prueba. asi que esa linea ya la comprove en un metodo de listar, y funciona. pero cuando lo hago asi falla:

```
def api(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        productos = Producto.objects.all()
        return JsonResponse(productos)
```

Ni siquiera intento meterlo en un input, solo lo imprimo en console. para ver que me devuelve:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'apis/',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    data:{
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
    },   
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response)
        
    },
    error: function(response){
        console.log(response)
    }
});

</script>
```

y me sale un error:

```
jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/apis/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
send    @   jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
ajax    @   jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
(anonymous) @   otto:79
```

como podria arreglarlo? o de que otra manera deberia hacerlo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pudiste resolver? el problema que veo es que en la variable productos es un queryset. y el queryset no se serializa como diccionario puedes probar con la función values() te retorna los valores, pero sigue siendo un queryset, puedes convertirlo en lista quedaría así:

```
productos = list(Producto.objects.all().values())
```

puedes consultar más en la documentación [aquí](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#values)